# a comparison between overlook and ignore

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I need to know whether the bold verbs below can alter the meaning of the following sentence or not (for me they both mean the same and exchangeable at least in this particular example:

> 1. I am really grateful to the coach; he **overlooked** my mistake against the opposing team in the final game.
> 2. I am really grateful to the coach; he **ignored** my mistake against the opposing team in the final game.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable  by a dictionary.  These two words are very similar in definition  but have different connotations depending on the context.

Comment: @ColleenV +1 I agree this case is not so obvious

Comment: There is also *intentional overlooking*. To be aware of but *chose to ignore*. See: *cronyism*.

Comment: @lurker I don't know what definition of cronyism you're working from, but the one I'm familiar with has nothing to do with overlook or ignore. Cronyism is favoritism shown to friends and family without regard for their qualifications, particularly in political appointments.

Comment: As in: cronies intentionally *overlook* their mates' mistakes. I was assuming everyone lived in my brain again. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Passive ignorance

To overlook is a type of ignorance without purpose, without recollection, without knowing.  It is **passive** Although, to overlook also suggests that the "ignorance" was performed with the eyes, since it is indeed conjoined with the verb `to look`.

Overlook isn't exactly the opposite of ignore because it is limited to vision.  You can overlook:

> An answer
>   Signs
>   Places

Therefore, oversight is only passive ignorance using the eyes.
But, you cannot overlook a smell, a taste, a feeling, or a sound.

English also has the words **oversee** and **overhear**, but neither indicate tru ignorance, but rather happenstance.

So the real "cousin" to ignoring something would be **to miss**, or **to fail to notice**, **fail to acknowledge**

- > They failed to notice the smell of pungent feet in the room
- > We failed to acknowledge that Peter was in pain
- > I missed the chance to hear hummingbird mating call

Each of these suggest an unintended form of ignorance,.. passive ignorance.

### Active ignorance

To ignore suggests that someone actively ignored something.  It doesn't matter which sense is used.

- > I ignored the smell of horse manure in the background
- > We ignored the stickiness of the change handed to us by that customer.
- > They ignored us yelling at them.
- > You ignored the sight of the carcass on the side of the road.

Each of these suggest that the ignorance was on purpose, it was intended, it was **active**

Answer (score 3):

Both words have the the same result, there being **no reaction** by the observer.

To **ignore** something, is to know it **exists** but **not pay any attention** to it.

> The people at dinner **ignored** the child's acting up.

To **overlook**(verb) something, is to **miss** it entirely, usually one does not know something existed and is **overlooked** until it is **pointed out later**.  **Overlooked** can also have the connotation of **ignored**.  Figuratively, one **looks over** an object since it is too low and/or out of sight, i.e. a small child (this should not be confused with *to take a **look over***, which is to observe in detail).

**Overlook**(verb) should not be confused with **an overlook**(noun), which is a **high vantage point** from which many things can be seen.

Usually, **mistakes** should **not be ignored**, if one finds a mistake it should be pointed out and corrected since **mistakes may cause future harm**.

Either **overlooked** or **ignored** can be used in your sentence, however, to me, **overlooked** sounds more **charitable** to the observer.

Your coach **ignored** what happened, and by doing so, **overlooked** your mistake.